# S3 Replication: Is it possible to replicate object from target replication bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 3 accounts: account A, account B and account C

Objects from account A source bucket are replicated to account B target bucket. Now I want to achieve that replicated object from account b target bucket should be replicated to bucket in account C.

Ofcourse account A has permission only to access account B and account B has permission to access only account C. I cannot change permissions.

so is it possible to replicate replicated objects in account B bucket to account C bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal S3 replication can't be used to replicate, replicated objects. You have to use [S3 Batch Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/s3-batch-replication-batch.html) instead:

> S3 Batch Replication provides you a way to replicate objects that existed before a replication configuration was in place, **objects that have previously been replicated**, and objects that have failed replication.